# ButterKnife returns null pointer in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

I'm using this code to call a CameraFragment using this library https://github.com/florent37/CameraFragment

Here is the MyCameraFragment.java code :

```
public class MyCameraFragment extends Fragment {



public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "camera";
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS = 931;

@Bind(R.id.action_settings)
CameraSettingsView settingsView;

@Bind(R.id.flash_switch_view)
FlashSwitchView flashSwitchView;

@Bind(R.id.front_back_camera_switcher)
CameraSwitchView cameraSwitchView;

@Bind(R.id.record_button)
RecordButton recordButton;

@Bind(R.id.cameraLayout)
View cameraLayout;

private FragmentActivity myContext;


public MyCameraFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 * @return A new instance of fragment MyCameraFragment.
 */
public static MyCameraFragment newInstance() {
    MyCameraFragment fragment = new MyCameraFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String[] permissions = {
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    final List<String> permissionsToRequest = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionsToRequest.add(permission);
            }
    }
    if (!permissionsToRequest.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS);
    } else addCamera();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(),view);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
@OnClick(R.id.flash_switch_view)
public void onFlashSwitcClicked() {
    final CameraFragmentApi cameraFragment = getCameraFragment();
    if (cameraFragment != null) {
        cameraFragment.toggleFlashMode();
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.front_back_camera_switcher)
public void onSwitchCameraClicked() {
    final CameraFragmentApi cameraFragment = getCameraFragment();
    if (cameraFragment != null) {
        cameraFragment.switchCameraTypeFrontBack();
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.record_button)
public void onRecordButtonClicked() {
    final CameraFragmentApi cameraFragment = getCameraFragment();
    if (cameraFragment != null) {
        cameraFragment.takePhotoOrCaptureVideo(new CameraFragmentResultListener() {

                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onVideoRecorded(String filePath) {

                                                   }

                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onPhotoTaken(byte[] bytes, String filePath) {
                                                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onPhotoTaken " + filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                   }
                                               },
                "/storage/self/primary",
                "photo");

    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.settings_view)
public void onSettingsClicked() {
    final CameraFragmentApi cameraFragment = getCameraFragment();
    if (cameraFragment != null) {
        cameraFragment.openSettingDialog();
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length != 0) {
        addCamera();
    }
}

public void addCamera() {

    final CameraFragment cameraFragment = CameraFragment.newInstance(new Configuration.Builder()
            .setCamera(Configuration.CAMERA_FACE_REAR).build());

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, cameraFragment,FRAGMENT_TAG)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();

    if (cameraFragment != null) {

        cameraFragment.setStateListener(new CameraFragmentStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCurrentCameraBack() {
                cameraSwitchView.displayBackCamera();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCurrentCameraFront() {
                cameraSwitchView.displayFrontCamera();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFlashAuto() {
                flashSwitchView.displayFlashAuto();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFlashOn() {
                flashSwitchView.displayFlashOn();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFlashOff() {
                flashSwitchView.displayFlashOff();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraSetupForPhoto() {
                recordButton.displayPhotoState();
                flashSwitchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCameraSetupForVideo() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRecordStateVideoReadyForRecord() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRecordStateVideoInProgress() {

            }

            @Override
            public void shouldRotateControls(int degrees) {
                ViewCompat.setRotation(cameraSwitchView, degrees);
                ViewCompat.setRotation(flashSwitchView, degrees);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartVideoRecord(File outputFile) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRecordStatePhoto() {
                recordButton.displayPhotoState();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopVideoRecord() {
                settingsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });

        cameraFragment.setControlsListener(new CameraFragmentControlsListener() {
            @Override
            public void lockControls() {
                cameraSwitchView.setEnabled(false);
                recordButton.setEnabled(false);
                settingsView.setEnabled(false);
                flashSwitchView.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void unLockControls() {
                cameraSwitchView.setEnabled(true);
                recordButton.setEnabled(true);
                settingsView.setEnabled(true);
                flashSwitchView.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void allowCameraSwitching(boolean allow) {
                cameraSwitchView.setVisibility(allow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void allowRecord(boolean allow) {
                recordButton.setEnabled(allow);
            }

            @Override
            public void setMediaActionSwitchVisible(boolean visible) {

            }

        });
    }
}

private CameraFragmentApi getCameraFragment() {
    return (CameraFragmentApi) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
}
```

}

Here is fragment_camera.xml Code :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.team31.plantdetection.fragments.MyCameraFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraLayout"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <com.github.florent37.camerafragment.widgets.CameraSettingsView
            android:id="@+id/settings_view"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            />

        <com.github.florent37.camerafragment.widgets.FlashSwitchView
            android:id="@+id/flash_switch_view"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <com.github.florent37.camerafragment.widgets.CameraSwitchView
            android:id="@+id/front_back_camera_switcher"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--android:background="#82000000"-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/record_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <com.github.florent37.camerafragment.widgets.RecordButton
            android:id="@+id/record_button"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app crush on launching with the problem : Attempt to ## Heading ##invoke virtual method 'void com.github.florent37.camerafragment.widgets.FlashSwitchView.displayFlashAuto()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 4):

See the [Doc](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

in gradle:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

in code:

use `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);`  instead of `ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(),view);`

```
 @Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        // TODO Use fields...
        return view;
      }
```

**EDIT**

use `@BindView(R.id.button1) Button button1;`

Comment: and in the place of Bind what do i use ?

Comment: i used BindView , Same problem , it doesn't work , and even with findViewById i get the same problem ....

Comment: why use `BindView`? The doc says to use: `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);`---make sure your layout is right and clean build the project

Comment: Using BindView in the declaration of the Views , and even with findViewById it don't work , the problem in in something else i think

Comment: `this` in place of `getActivity()` fixed the issue

Comment: you saved me from a minor headache

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to this answer, bear in mind that `onCreate` is called *before* `onCreateView`.

If you have code before the ButterKnife is bound it will obviously be null, I ran into issues as I didn't bother looking up the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) when converting an Activity.